# Including ObjectiveGit library in iOS app

Tags: ios5, frameworks, xcode4.3, dynamic-library, libgit2

When opening the ObjectieGitFramework.xcodeproj file I can now build the iOS scheme successfully. A whole lot of experimenting was required though. Lets start from the beginning – how I did that.

**What I did:**

First I cloned a fork of ObjectiveGit.

```
git clone git@github.com:Eonil/objective-git.git --recurse-submodules
cd objective-git
cd ./Scripts/libgit2-make-ios/; sh ./download-make-clean-deploy.sh "./../../libgit2.a"; cd ../..
```

Src: https://github.com/libgit2/objective-git/pull/54

Opening the project and building now results in one error and one warning. I let Xcode automatically update the project settings to solve the warning.
[image: Errors]

Now I go to the `libgit2` directory and build using [cmake](http://www.cmake.org/):

```
$ mkdir build && cd build
$ cmake ..
$ cmake --build .
```

Src: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2

This result, among other things, in the `libgit2.0.15.0.dylib` file being created.
[image: Image of the file in finder]

I drag it into the Xcode and add it to ObjectiveGit and the iOS target. Now I go to the build phases tab for ObjectiveGit-iOS and make it look like this:

[image]

**The problem**

At this moment I could build the project, and I could create classes within it successfully using the `ObjectiveGit`. However when I dragged the project inside another project, added `ObjectiveGit-iOS` as a target dependence and added `libObjectiveGit-iOS.a` in `link binary with libraries` I couldn't import `ObjectiveGit/ObjectiveGit.h` plus I was getting some other weird errors (see images below). I know very little about libraries in xcode so I don't know at all why this is not working.

[image]
[image]

Now, this is an error I got once but not anymore. I don't know what I was doing to cause it.
[image]

**Update**

```
 $(SRCROOT)/frameworks/ObjectiveGit/Classes
 $(SRCROOT)/frameworks/ObjectiveGit/libgit2/include
 $(SRCROOT)/frameworks/ObjectiveGit/Classes/Categories
```

When adding this to `header search path` something strange happens. It result in no files not being found, but 70 other Mach-o errors instead.

```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic Libraries are not supported by iOS. You have to use static libraries.

To be clear: Of course iOS supports dynamic libraries, but only these which are distributed by apple.

Comment: What about a static library which itself contains a dynamic library? Couldn't that work if one could get the dylib (libgit2) to be included in the static `ObjectiveGit`?

Comment: This wouldn't change anything because the libgit2.dylib wouldn't be available on the device. Why don't you just compile libgit2 static?

Comment: I feel very, very stupid now. I don't know why I didn't do that. I have done it now and it seem to work fine, but I can't really tell for sure because of some mach-o errors with the libz as well, which working on them.